Setspace interacting with Linguex and messing up footnote numbering
I want the example numbers in my footnotes to be in roman numerals, but in arabic numerals in main body. This is the default with linguex.
However when I load the setspace package, it changes the numbers of linguex examples inside footnotes to arabic numerals. Here is an MWE - the issue appears once I uncomment the \usepackage{setspace}.
    \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{linguex}

% \usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

I am using Linguex to write examples.\footnote{In footnotes, the examples show up with Arabic and not Roman numerals.

\ex. This is an example!

}

\ex. This is an example.

\end{document}

Any ideas how to fix?

Welcome to TeX.SE!

load linguex after setspace (but setspace should be adapted so that it stops to overwrite @footnotetext.)

Worked! Thanks so much!
